# one cloud server and running multiple node and mongo project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, server, debian

I bought a cloud server from digitalocean. I have a problem

I wrote a project that using node js web services and mongodb database I'm trying to setup node js and mongo db its okay but my problem is how can I deploy my node js app which will use mongodb  and using my custom domain.

Now my domain at natro.com I can't complex with all of them any tutorial that you have known or something else can be helpful?

I don't know much about server management.

My server can be ubuntu or debian, doesn't matter, depends on tutorial or some blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is add your domain in **Network** area of DigitalOcean Panel. Use this tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean

Now, follow this tutorial for deploying your nodejs app with nginx

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04